# Git not found in path by SonarQube using Jenkins

Tags: c#, git, jenkins, sonarqube

My setup is as follows:

- Jenkins on Windows Server 2012 system
- Git installed on the same system
- SonarQube on separate server, executed by SonarQube Runner (not Maven)

I have a Jenkins project that pulls source code (C#) using Git, compiles it, then presents it for analysis to SonarQube. The pull, compile, and analysis all work, but I am getting error messages saying:

16:05:58.883 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for *(source file path)*

16:05:58.883 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: *(source file path)* Reason: The git blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I first assumed that Git had to be installed on the SonarQube server, too, but there is another project using a similar setup and the same SonarQube server that is working correctly, adding "blame" information to SonarQube's source code listings.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe GIT is not in the PATH of the user that runs this Jenkins job?

Comment: It's in the path. Oddly enough, it seems to have started working on its own. Go figure.